# Using touch enabled Windows over Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, ipad

I have a Windows 7 VM in "the cloud" and i control this using my iPad or iPhone on the road, or Laptop or desktop when not as mobile... But Windows 7 over this interface is not very touch friendly... I have used OnLive's Desktop service as a test, and noticed that what ever magic they use, Windows thinks its fully touch enabled, and all gestures and touches from the iPad are sent to Windows to work its magic with... What i am wondering is, can this be done with current Windows 7 VMs and Remote Desktop? Is this something that can be done in the Protocol and someone just needs to enable it on their iPad client, or is there some magic that OnLive are doing to get this working?

Comment: OnLive is doing magic. Windows 7 doesn't, Windows 8 might but we'll have to wait to know...

Comment: Who/what company is providing your hosted Windows 7 VM in "the cloud"?

Comment: the company is called onlive... http://desktop.onlive.com/ is the web site. they only offer Windows 7 and only offer access to the iPad... Currently anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [Splashtop](http://www.splashtop.com/) which seems to do some of this. I have used it on Windows 8 and an iPad, and other than being a little laggy, it does the job.